# How to get Previous month sales total in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am Working on an SSRS report. I have a dataset with the following data points: salesid, items, amount, date.

@start_date and @end_date are the two report parameters.

I have created a textbox (Sum(sale) from @Start_date to @end_date ) now I want to create a text box for (Sum(sales) for the @start_date(previous) to @end_date(previous) month.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that if you are not applying the parameters to your query so that you get all the data back... you just change the summation query to be:  sum(sales) with parameters using expressions and the expression being: =DateAdd("M",-1,Parameters!start_date.value) or something very close to that expression.